# repaint works only for some code

Tags: paint, drjava

So i'm trying to make a game where a block falls from the sky and you have to dodge it. I use keylistener to move the player, and a timer to move the block that falls down. I can move the player just fine, repaint works there; it's the red block that's the problem.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class boxface extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

  private int x=0, y=0;
  final static java.util.Timer tmr = new java.util.Timer();

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
      moveRight();
    else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
      moveLeft(); }
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

  Rectangle player = new Rectangle(x, 400, 50, 50);
  Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(0, 0, 700, 750);
  int x2 = ((int)((Math.random()*3)))*50;
  Rectangle enemy = new Rectangle(x2, y, 50, 50);
  int temp = 0;

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(bg);
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fill(player);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(enemy); }

  public void moveLeft() {
    if(x > 0) {
      x -= 50;
      player.setLocation(x, 400);
      repaint();}}

  public void moveRight() {
    if(x < 100) {
      x += 50;
      player.setLocation(x, 400);
      repaint();} }

  public void enemyDown() {
    if(enemy.getBounds().y == 400) {
      x2=((int)((Math.random()*3)))*50;
      y=0;
      enemy.setLocation(x2, y);
      repaint(); }
    else {
      y = y + 50;
      enemy.setLocation(x2, y);
      repaint();} }

  public void intersector() {
    if(enemy.intersects(player))
      tmr.cancel(); }

  public boxface(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setBounds(400, 200, 156, 479);
        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(156, 0));
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.getContentPane().add(new boxface());
        f.setVisible(true);

      }

    });

    tmr.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      public void run()
      {
        boxface exec = new boxface();
        exec.enemyDown();
        exec.intersector();
      }
    },0,10000);

  }

}
```

After a bit of experimenting, only the bottom part of enemyDown() is ever activated (the "else" statement, not the "if"), yet it resets the y co-ordinate of the red block every time. Regardless, the program never repaints the enemy anyways, so it wouldn't matter. Over the past 72 hours I've gotten 2 hours of sleep, so maybe this is a really stupid, simple mistake, but right now I can't figure out a way to fix this.

Comment: get some sleep kid. @pauloSantos

Comment: Will do! I had 4 culminating assignments due today, with minimal warning on all of them, and they're worth 15-30% of my mark. Thankfully I don't have anything to worry about today, or at least for a few days, until finals come up.

Comment: greek to me. on your on.

Comment: is the game in html?

Comment: Nope, making it in a program called drjava

Comment: more greek. I use js woven into html.